# I got less quality video when I uploaded it on Youtube

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording, youtube

I recorded a video using Camtasia software trial version. I produced the video in MP4 HD. The video quality is very good when I play it on my desktop. When I uploaded the video to Youtube, the video on Youtube had less quality than it has at my desktop.

So can you help me have the very good quality (supoorts HD) at Youtube or at least having the same quality as it has at my desktop?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Compression/Format of Audio Change when Uploaded to YouTube?](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/will-compression-format-of-audio-change-when-uploaded-to-youtube)

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to maintain the original quality when you upload a video to youtube since youtube reencodes **all** videos. For a detailed explanation of why it does that, check [my answer here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/will-compression-format-of-audio-change-when-uploaded-to-youtube/15815#15815). To minimise quality loss, export your video with a high bitrate.

Answer (score 0):

Try these export settings:

- For a 720p export, make sure your data rate is no smaller than 5 Mbps.
  For a 1080p export, make sure your data rate is no smaller than 10 Mbps.
- Codec: H264.
- Field order: progressive usually (depending on your raw footage).
- Aspect: square pixel usually (depending on your raw footage).
- Audio: AAC, 4100Hz, Maximum Bitrate.
- Maximum render quality.